# In Django, how to use split() to separate a string of dropdown items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

`trips` in the `def trips` function returns something like `x-y` (so team_home-team_away). `trips` is showing correctly in the second dropdown.

I want to separate `x` and `y`, creating two variables:

- `x` will be variable `a`
- `y` will be variable `b`

I will be I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
a,b = trips.split('-')
```

I don't know if `a,b = trips.split('-')` is correct in setting up your code.

My goal is to select the item in the combobox, then click on the button which starts the `def test1` function and displays the text in the textarea (`def result`). Should I use the `split` code in the `def trips` function or elsewhere? Or do I have to create a new function? The `render` of the `split` in which HTML page should it be? (in trips.html which is the dropdown or in result.html which is the textarea?)

**ERROR:** I get the error: `core.models.Full_Record.DoesNotExist: Full_Record matching query does not exist.`

This happens because if I insert a, b = trips.split('-'), the second dropdown is no longer populated. I don't know why this happens. While if I delete x, y = trips.split('-'), then the second dropdown is populated correctly

Can you show me how I can fix it? Thank you all!

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Full_Record
import random

def trip_selector(request):
    campionati = Full_Record.objects.values(pk=F('campionato__id'), name=F('campionato__name')).distinct()
    trips = []
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'campionati': campionati, 'trips': trips})

def trips(request):
    if request.GET.get("campionato"):
        campionato = request.GET.get('campionato')
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=campionato)

    elif request.GET.get("trips"):
        selected_trip_id = int(request.GET.get('trips'))
        selected_trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=selected_trip_id)
        request.session.update({"selected_trip_id": selected_trip_id})
        trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=selected_trip.campionato)

    #HERE SPLIT ????
    a,b = trips.split('-')
    context = {'trips': trips, 'a':a, 'b':b}

    return render(request, 'trips.html', context)


def test1(request):
    trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
    sentence = ["The selected trip is ", "Congratulations you have selected the trip ", "You have currently selected travel ", "The currently selected trip is "]
    return f"{random.choice(sentence)} {trip.a}-{trip.b}"


def result(request):
    test_print_in_result = test1(request)
    return render(request,"result.html", {"test_print_in_result": test_print_in_result})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
from django.contrib import admin

#### BASIC DATA ####
       
#Campionato
class Campionato(models.Model):
    stagione = models.ForeignKey(Stagione, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


#Teams
class Teams(models.Model):
    stagione = models.ForeignKey(Stagione, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campionato = models.ForeignKey(Campionato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    
#### FULL RECORD ####

class Full_Record(models.Model):

    campionato = models.ForeignKey(Campionato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    team_home = ChainedForeignKey(
        Teams,
        related_name='team_home_name',
        chained_field="campionato",
        chained_model_field="campionato",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    
    team_away = ChainedForeignKey(
        Teams,
        related_name='team_away_name',
        chained_field="campionato",
        chained_model_field="campionato",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)

    def partita(self):
        return f"{self.team_home}-{self.team_away}"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.campionato
```

**forms.py**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

<!-- First Combobox -->
<label for="id_campionato">Country</label>

<select name="campionato" id="id_campionato" hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#id_trip" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" hx-trigger="change">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  
{% for campionato in campionati %}
<option value="{{ campionato.pk }}">{{ campionato.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<!-- Second Combobox -->
<label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
{% include "trips.html" %}

.......
.......

{% endblock %}
```

**trips.html**

```
<!-- Second Combobox -->
<select name="trips" id="id_trip" style="width:200px;"  hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" hx-trigger="change" hx-swap="none">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
    {% for trip in trips %}
      <option value="{{ trip.id }}">{{ trip.team_home }}-{{ trip.team_away }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you trying to use `split()` on something that is not a string.

This line will return Full_Record object, not a string:

```
trips = Full_Record.objects.filter(campionato=selected_trip.campionato)
```

It will  be helpful if you added description of the error if there's traceback.

Comment: I am getting the error: core.models.Full_Record.DoesNotExist: Matching query Full_Record does not exist. This happens because if you insert x, y = trips[0].split('-'), the second dropdown is no longer populated. While if it clears x, y = trips[0].split('-'), then the second dropdown is populated. Why? How to fix?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You may have to check what's going on this line

```
trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
```

Especially the part where you were retrieving somewhat an id from a request session.

`request.session.get("selected_trip_id")`
It either returns None, which isn't an id in your db, or it actually returns a value, but that id doesn't exist in your db.

You can test that logic to check.

Also, in your function **test1**, you should replace this line

```
trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
```

With

```
try:
    trip = Full_Record.objects.get(id=request.session.get("selected_trip_id"))
except Full_Record.DoesNotExist as error:
    # Do something to handle this case
    # and also terminate the logic here
```